# I want to create an event on window1 as soon as window 2 closes JAVAFX (Added More Detail)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have 2 windows .
Window1 launches window 2 by a button click. 
I want to change the text of an TextField in window 1 as soon as windows2 closes.

Is there any way to create an event in window1 as soon as window 2 closes.

I am using fxml so each window has different controller and fxml files.

1st window is mostly a table view and some textfields to fill it with data which is connected by mysql database here is the code.

```
    package sample;

    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
    import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.stage.Modality;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    public class TableData implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Data, String> COMPANYCOL;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Data, ?> DATECOL;

        @FXML
        private TextArea AddressField;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Data, Integer> IDCOL;

        @FXML
        TextField RefernceField;

        @FXML
        private Label searchLabel;

        @FXML
        private MenuItem FilterMenuItem;

        @FXML
        private Label FilterLabel;

        @FXML
        private TextField FilterField;


        @FXML
        private TableView<Data> TABLEVIEWID;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Data, Double> PHONENOCOL;

        @FXML
        private TextField SearchField;

        Stage stage;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Data, String> ADDRESSCOL;

        @FXML
        private TextField PhoneNoField;

        @FXML
        private TextField NameField;

        @FXML
        private Button AddButton;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Data, String> NAMECOL;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Data, String> REFRENCECOL;

        @FXML
        private TextField CompanyField;
        Stage primaryStage= new Stage();





        private Config config = new Config();
        ObservableList<Data> Mainlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            Connection drdoConnection = DatabaseConnection.getConnectionDrdo();
            Connection MydatabaseConnection = DatabaseConnection.getConnectionOwn();

        public TableData() throws Exception {
        }


    int q;
       RefrenceController refrenceController= new RefrenceController();
        int icno=0;


        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

            if(drdoConnection!=null&&MydatabaseConnection!=null) {

                RefernceField.setEditable(false);







                config.factory(IDCOL, "id");
                config.factory(NAMECOL, "name");
                config.factory(COMPANYCOL, "company");
                config.factory(ADDRESSCOL, "address");
                config.factory(PHONENOCOL,"phoneno");
                config.factory(REFRENCECOL, "refrence");

                try {
                    Statement statement= drdoConnection.createStatement();

                    ResultSet resultSet= statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM drdomy");

                    while (resultSet.next()){
                         q=  resultSet.getInt("id");
                        Mainlist.addAll(new Data(q,resultSet.getString("name"),resultSet.getString("company"),
                                resultSet.getString("address"),resultSet.getDouble("phoneno"),resultSet.getString("Refrence")));
                    }

                    TABLEVIEWID.getItems().addAll(Mainlist);
                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Ref.fxml"));
                    primaryStage.setTitle("Ref Window");
                    primaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

//this is the code that is giving that nullPointerException
//I have tried Every Possible Step But Coudn't resolve it 
                    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{

                         RefernceField.setText(String.valueOf(refrenceController.OnSubmitButtonClicked()));

                          });


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            else {
                config.alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Database Server May be Down Check Logs");

            }
        }

        @FXML
        void TableAddButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
            String query= "INSERT INTO drdomy (id,name,company,address,phoneno,Refrence) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = drdoConnection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setInt(1,++q);
            statement.setString(2,NameField.getText());
            statement.setString(3,CompanyField.getText());
            statement.setString(4,AddressField.getText());
            statement.setDouble(5,Double.parseDouble(PhoneNoField.getText()));
            statement.setString(6,RefernceField.getText());

            statement.execute();
            TABLEVIEWID.getItems().clear();

            Mainlist.addAll(new Data(q,NameField.getText(),CompanyField.getText(),AddressField.getText(),Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(PhoneNoField.getText())),RefernceField.getText()));
            TABLEVIEWID.getItems().addAll(Mainlist);

            NameField.clear();
            CompanyField.clear();
            AddressField.clear();
            PhoneNoField.clear();
            RefernceField.clear();
            statement.close();

            stage = (Stage) AddButton.getScene().getWindow();

            stage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
                try {
                    drdoConnection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            });










        }

        @FXML
        void FilterActionMenuItem(ActionEvent event) {

            FilterField.setScaleY(1);
            FilterField.setScaleX(1);
            FilterField.setScaleZ(1);
            FilterLabel.setScaleX(1);
            FilterLabel.setScaleY(1);
            FilterLabel.setScaleZ(1);


        }

        @FXML
        void KeyRealesedFilterField() {


            FilteredList<Data> dataFilteredList = new FilteredList<Data>(Mainlist,p-> true);
            FilterField.textProperty().addListener((observable ,oldValue,newValue )->{

                dataFilteredList.setPredicate(data -> {

                    if (newValue== null|| newValue.isEmpty())
                        return true;

                    String lowercase= newValue.toLowerCase();
                    int p=data.getId();


                    if (data.getAddress().toLowerCase().contains(lowercase)){
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(String.valueOf(p).contains(newValue)){
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(String.valueOf(data.getPhoneno()).contains(newValue))
                        return true;

                   else if (data.getRefrence().toLowerCase().contains(lowercase)){
                       return true;
                   }
                    else if(data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowercase)){
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if (data.getCompany().toLowerCase().contains(lowercase)){
                        return true;
                    }




                    return false;

                });

                SortedList<Data> dataSortedList = new SortedList<Data>(dataFilteredList);
                dataSortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(TABLEVIEWID.comparatorProperty());
                TABLEVIEWID.setItems(dataSortedList);
            });


        }



        @FXML
        void OnRefAction() throws IOException {



            primaryStage.showAndWait();




        }



    }
```

So the case is that i am filling data to mysql database using this scene by manually entering data to the textfields but the refrence field's OnAction is connected to another scene that is going set the text of refrence field as soon as it closes

here is the scene controller that opens by the refrence field

```
    package sample;

    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
    import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.State;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    public class RefrenceController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private Button btnsubmit;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<SData, String> GROUPCOL;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<SData, String> DESIGCOL;

        @FXML
        private TextField SearchFieldS;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<SData, Integer> ICNOCOL;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<SData, String> NAMECOLS;

        @FXML
        TableView<SData> TABLEID;

        private TableData tableData;

        private Config config = new Config();
        private int icno=0;


        Connection SDRDODATA = DatabaseConnection.getConnectionOwn();
        ObservableList<SData> MainListS = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public RefrenceController() throws Exception {
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

            config.factory(ICNOCOL, "ID");
            config.factory(NAMECOLS, "NAME");
            config.factory(GROUPCOL, "GROUP");
            config.factory(DESIGCOL, "DESIGNATION");

            try {
                Statement statement = SDRDODATA.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sdata");

                while (rs.next()) {

                    MainListS.addAll(new SData(rs.getInt("IC_NO"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("GroupS"),
                            rs.getString("Designation")));
                }

                statement.close();
                SDRDODATA.close();



    //            OnSubmitButtonClicked();



            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @FXML
        void OnkeyRelesedMethod() {

            FilteredList<SData> filteredData = new FilteredList<SData>(MainListS, p -> true);
            SearchFieldS.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                filteredData.setPredicate(sData -> {

                    if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty())
                        return false;

                    String lowercase = newValue.toLowerCase();

                    if (String.valueOf(sData.getID()).contains(newValue))
                        return true;
                    else if (sData.getNAME().toLowerCase().contains(lowercase))
                        return true;
                    else if (sData.getGROUP().toLowerCase().contains(lowercase))
                        return true;
                    else if (sData.getDESIGNATION().toLowerCase().contains(lowercase))
                        return true;

                    return false;
                });

                SortedList<SData> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
                sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(TABLEID.comparatorProperty());
                TABLEID.setItems(sortedList);

            });


        }

        @FXML
        int OnSubmitButtonClicked()  {



            SData sData = TABLEID.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                icno = sData.getID();
                Stage stage = (Stage) btnsubmit.getScene().getWindow();


        }

        @FXML
        void OnMouseClicked() {


            SData sData=TABLEID.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            icno= sData.getID();
            System.out.println(icno);
return icno;

        }
        }
```

i have tried every possible step but every thing gives that nullpointerException
please tell me how to solve this problem.

if there is any explanation needed please ask .

here is the stackTrace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:218)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:583)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at sample.TableData.OnRefAction(TableData.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:178)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:216)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:246)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.RefrenceController.OnSubmitButtonClicked(RefrenceController.java:129)
    at sample.TableData.lambda$initialize$0(TableData.java:142)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.stage.Window.fireEvent(Window.java:1120)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:820)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)
    at javafx.stage.Window.hide(Window.java:947)
    at sample.RefrenceController.OnSubmitButtonClicked(RefrenceController.java:151)
    ... 121 more
```

Comment: My question got a -ve point why.?

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question? If yes please comment.   May be i'll explain you.

Comment: Commenting to earn

Comment: That next award

Comment: In your button handler that launches the second window, your last piece of code should be show and wait. Right below this show and wait method is where you should put your '//change text in TextField.'

Comment: that is still null

Comment: If you are getting a null pointer error.  You need to read your stack trace  to find out what piece of code is causing the error. Or post your stacktrace

Comment: Wait a minute i am posting it.

Comment: i have added the stackTrace ..

Comment: It tells you  the problem is here: at sample.RefrenceController.OnSubmitButtonClicked(RefrenceController.java:129). Which line of code in RefrenceController is line 129?

Comment: this is SData sData = TABLEID.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

Comment: SData is a user class where all getter and setters are created for the window2 table

Comment: Which is Refrence Controller window

Comment: You may need to do some type of null check or java optional. I would comment that line out then do system.out.println(tableid.getSeleted...); to see if I am getting the correct output at this point.  I don't know if wrapping this line in if(tableid.getselectoin.... != nulll){...} would work.

Comment: I have Checked the code for null value of (tableid.getSelected....) its not null, by doing System.out.print it prints out the value but when i take this value and return it to the another controller it gets null every single time,         thanks for your comments.

Comment: Int onsubmitclick () chang int to void

Comment: When you run you test this time, make sure that you have selected a table row before you press your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a event as soon as a window closes 
Use setOnCloseRequest by using the stage of window which is about to close.

Answer (score 1):

Set `EventHandler` on close request or on hidden or on hidding. Pick what you need:

```
Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
secondaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(ev -> {
    //change text in TextField
});
secondaryStage.setOnHidden(ev -> {
    //or change text in TextField
});
secondaryStage.setOnHiding(ev -> {
    //or change text in TextField
});
```

Comment: Both windows has different controller.

Comment: It's up to you, how you handle data exchange between controllers. There are many posts on SO, about this problem.

Comment: Hey thanks it works now but only when i click red cross on top right, but not by button  primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
                    RefernceField.setText("Man");
                }

Comment: Button is also used to close the scene in controller of window 2